# use socket send udp message to broadcast address encounter java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, sockets, netty, vert.x

I use vert.x DatagramSocket write a UDP server and client,when client send message to server encounter exception：java.net.SocketException: Permission denied，but run the same code in my windows machine,the code works fine。

The server code：

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
DatagramSocket socket = vertx.createDatagramSocket();

socket.listen(5230, "10.10.10.234", event -> {
    if (event.succeeded()) {
        socket.handler(event1 -> System.out.println("get event"));
    }
});
```

The client code：

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
DatagramSocket socket = vertx.createDatagramSocket();
socket.send("hello", 5230, "10.10.10.255", event -> {
    if (event.succeeded()) {
        System.out.println("send success");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed");
        System.out.println(event.cause());
    }
});
```

I use ifconfig cmd get the broadcast address:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.234  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:feb0:3bce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:b0:3b:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 873959230  bytes 443622938789 (413.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 853529342  bytes 207859604378 (193.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**I run the code use root user too**

Comment: Can you try and use some different port? Example 8898

Comment: Just tried your code just changed IP that you have provided to 127.0.0.1 and everything works as expected.

Comment: @Pendula I use MulticastSocket from jdk,it works well.